# Symbolic link one directory of files to another

Tags: symbolic-link

```
ka@karl:~$ ls ./test_source_sym
file.txt
ka@karl:~$ ln -s ./test_source_sym ./test_sym/dir
ka@karl:~$ ls -la ./test_sym/dir 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 karl karl 17 jun 28 09:56 ./test_sym/dir -> ./test_source_sym
ka@karl:~$ cat ./test_sym/dir/file.txt
cat: ./test_sym/dir/file.txt: No such file or directory
```

Is there something I've misunderstood here about symbolic links?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ln -s ./test_source_sym ./test_sym/dir
$ ls -al ./test_sym/dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 users 17 jun 28 18:25 ./test_sym/dir -> ./test_source_sym
```

this is a link to the wrong directory; it should be the parent directory

```
$ rm ./test_sym/dir
$ ln -s ../test_source_sym ./test_sym/dir
$ ls -al ./test_sym/dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 users 18 jun 28 18:25 ./test_sym/dir -> ../test_source_sym
$ cat ./test_sym/dir/file.txt 
hello world!
```

easier to understand when you first descend to the test_sym directory:

```
$ rm ./test_sym/dir
$ cd test_sym
$ ln -s ../test_source_sym dir
$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 145 user1 users 12288 jun 28 18:23 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 user1 users    18 jun 28 18:31 dir -> ../test_source_sym
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1 users  4096 jun 28 18:31 .
$ cat dir/file.txt 
hello world!
```

Comment: Let's sum up, when we using relative paths for symlink creation, we need to be in the directory where the symlink will exist, otherwise we need to use full paths.

Answer (score 0):

### DERP

1. Make sure `./test_source_sym` directory exists
2. Make sure `./test_sym` directory exists
3. `ln -s ./test_source_sym/*  ./test_sym`

Comment: You have extra `*` there. That'd make a file symlink

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure why this is the case, but I was able to correct your problem after replicating it by doing the following:

```
steven:~/.tmp$ ls ./test_source_sym
file.txt
steven:~/.tmp$ mkdir test_sym
steven:~/.tmp$ cd test_sym
steven:~/.tmp/test_sym$ ln -vs ~/.tmp/test_source_sym dir
'dir' -> '/home/steven/.tmp/test_source_sym'
steven:~/.tmp/test_sym$ cat dir/file.txt
This is a file with text in it.
Line 2 of text.
3
Last line, goodbye!
```

It appears to be an issue with the `ln` command determining the complete path of `test_source_sym` and therefore failing to create a proper symbolic link to that directory. Using colored output for `ls` displayed the symbolic link created using your method as being broken.

Hope this helps!